# Validate input using regex

Tags: c++, regex, validation

I honestly don't know what I am doing wrong. I have checked the regex expression in http://regexpal.com/ and it works just fine

here is my code:

```
std::string text = "1.98";
std::regex regex_number("((\b[0-9]+)?\.)?[0-9]+\b");  
bool isValid = std::regex_match(text, regex_number);
```

It should be valid for integers and doubles 
Ex:

- 1.2
- 1
- 1.99
- 0.6

Not valid for

- aa
- dd
- 1.2h
- 1,6

I get Non Valid text for everything.

Comment: If you are trying to check if string has valid int or double you can use lexical_cast from boost. boost::lexical_cast<int,string>(text),  boost::lexical_cast<double,string>(text) should help. Lexical_cast throws an exception if text is not a valid number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to escape your backslashes in the string literal:

```
std::regex regex_number("((\\b[0-9]+)?\\.)?[0-9]+\\b");
```

Answer (score 1):

You also stuck that first word delimiter in the wrong spot. It should be outside the optional sections:

```
"\\b(([0-9]+)?\\.)?[0-9]+\\b"
```

(Sorry for the additional answer; I still don't have the rep to add comments.)